# EF подсчет среднего значения затрат в день

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

необходимо подсчитать среднее значение потраченных денег(по дням, а не по количеству).
вот класс

```
    [Key]
    public Int32 ExpensesId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set
        {
            date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double Cost
    {
        get { return cost; }
        set
        {
            cost = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Category
    {
        get { return category; }
        set
        {
            category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

вот код для расчета среднего значения(еще и проверяется диапазон даты), но он высчитывает среднее значение по количеству

**UPD**: получилось следующее

```
        public static double GetAvgOverTime(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string category)
    {
        ExpensesContext context = new ExpensesContext();
        double result = 0;
        if (category == "Все")
        {
            result = context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate &&
                                         e.Date.Value <= endDate).Count() == 0
                                         ? 0d
                                         : context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate &&
                                                                        e.Date.Value <= endDate)
                            .GroupBy(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.Date.Value))
                            .Select(p => p.Average(e => e.Cost))
                            .FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            result = context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate &&
                                                  e.Date.Value <= endDate &&
                                                  e.Category == category).Count() == 0
                         ? 0d
                         : context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate &&
                                                        e.Date.Value <= endDate &&
                                                        e.Category == category)
            .GroupBy(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.Date.Value))
            .Select(p => p.Average(e => e.Cost))
            .FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Данный метод возвращает только 1 значение (среднее первой группы).
А мне нужно получить среднее по всем группам.
Что хочу на конкретном примере:
в 1-й день я делал 3 покупки (2, 4 и 6 рублей соответственно)
во 2-й день 1 покупка на 10 рублей
в 3-й день 2 покупки (3 и 5 рублей)
нынешний метод вернет 4(среднее за 1 день),
а мне надо среднее из средних, получается (4 + 10 + 4) / 3 = 6

Comment: Если у Вас какое-то собственное видение среднего значения не по количеству, то хоть уточните это виденье и что должно получиться.

Comment: @AlexKrass подправил. нужно чтобы за день затраты складывались

Comment: Тогда там надо будет сделать перед вычислением GroupBy по дням и уже потом вычислить среднее Average и вернуть список.

Comment: @AlexKrass после groupby не знаю как и что писать + не будет ли он при группировке еще и время учитывать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

собственно вот. Разница в том, что один метод считает только те дни, в которые происходили какие-либо расходы, а второй просто количество дней

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Метод для расчета средних затрат в в день (сумма / количество дней)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDate">Начало периода</param>
    /// <param name="endDate">Конец периода</param>
    /// <param name="category">Категория</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static double GetAvgSpent(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string category)
    {
        ExpensesContext context = new ExpensesContext();
        TimeSpan timeSpan = endDate - startDate;
        double result = GetTotalSpent(startDate, endDate, category) / (timeSpan.Days + 1);
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Потрачено в среднем за 1 поход в магазин
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDate">Дата начала периода</param>
    /// <param name="endDate">Дата конца периода</param>
    /// <param name="category">Категория</param>
    /// <returns>Значение средних затрат за 1 поход в магазин</returns>
    public static double GetAvgOverTime(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string category)
    {
        ExpensesContext context = new ExpensesContext();
        double result = 0;
        var tmp = new List<double>();
        if (category == "Все")
        {
            tmp = context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate &&
                                          e.Date.Value <= endDate).Count() == 0
                                          ? new List<double> { 0 }
                                          : context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate &&
                                                                         e.Date.Value <= endDate)
                             .GroupBy(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.Date.Value))
                             .Select(p => p.Sum(e => e.Cost)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate &&
                                                  e.Date.Value <= endDate &&
                                                  e.Category == category).Count() == 0
                         ? new List<double> { 0 }
                         : context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate &&
                                                        e.Date.Value <= endDate &&
                                                        e.Category == category)
            .GroupBy(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.Date.Value))
            .Select(p => p.Sum(e => e.Cost)).ToList();
        }
        foreach (var item in tmp)
        {
            result += item;
        }
        return result / tmp.Count;
    }
 /// <summary>
    /// Метод для расчета суммы затрат
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDate">Начало периода</param>
    /// <param name="endDate">Конец периода</param>
    /// <param name="category">Категория</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static double GetTotalSpent(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string category)
    {
        ExpensesContext context = new ExpensesContext();
        double result = 0;
        if(category == "Все")
        {
            if (context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate && 
                                             e.Date.Value <= endDate)
                                 .Count() != 0)
            {
                result = context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate &&
                                                      e.Date.Value <= endDate)
                                          .Sum(e => e.Cost);
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            if (context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate && 
                                             e.Date.Value <= endDate &&
                                             e.Category == category)
                                 .Count() != 0)
            {
                result = context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= startDate &&
                                                      e.Date.Value <= endDate &&
                                                      e.Category == category)
                                          .Sum(e => e.Cost);
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сделать группировку по датам `GroupBy(e => e.Date.Date)` и потом посчитать среднее значение для каждой группы `Select(p => p.Average(e => e.Cost).ToString("N2"))`.

```
res = context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= selectedStartDate &&
                                   e.Date.Value <= selectedEndDate).Count() == 0 ? "0" :
      context.Expensies.Where(e => e.Date.Value >= selectedStartDate &&
                                   e.Date.Value <= selectedEndDate)
                       .GroupBy(e => e.Date.Date)
                       .Select(p => p.Average(e => e.Cost).ToString("N2"));
```

**UPD: пример использования**

```
    class Test
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public double Cost { get; set; }

        public Test(DateTime date, double cost)
        {
            Date = date;
            Cost = cost;
        }  
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Test> list = new List<Test>()
            {
                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0)), 100),
                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0)), 50),
                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0)), 10),
                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0)), 110),

                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(2,0,0,0)), 100),
                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(2,0,0,0)), 50),
                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(2,0,0,0)), 10),
                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(2,0,0,0)), 110),

                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(-1,0,0,0)), 100),
                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(-1,0,0,0)), 50),

                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(3,0,0,0)), 10),
                  new Test(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(3,0,0,0)), 110)
            };

            var result = list.GroupBy(p => p.Date.Date).Select(p => p.Average(e => e.Cost).ToString("N2"));

            Console.WriteLine(result.Aggregate((i,j) => $"{i}{Environment.NewLine}{j}"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но он выводит почему то тот же результат что и мой

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr может у вас там дата одинаковая для всех? Добавил пример с разными датами, что бы можно было проверить корректность кода.

Comment: p.Date.Date - не хочет работать в LINQ. нужно использовать `DbFunctions.TruncateTime()`. дополнил первый пост. спасибо за помощь в решении задачи